# Javascript - Count characters of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to create a function that will search a string for an anchor tag, when it finds one, count the characters between  and return that number.  I am doing this for an editor that is counting the number of characters in a textarea because the textarea has a limit the user can enter and I don't want the characters in a link to count against that total.

If I have this in the textarea:

```
This is what it looks like here <a href="http://www.bmhl.com">Placeholder</a>.  Please click the link to go to the page.
```

There are 32 characters prior to the anchor, 11 in between and 42 after for a total of 85.  In the anchor tag there are 34 characters that I don't want to go towards the count.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean count the abcd characters between <a href="#">abcd</a> like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want just to strip just the anchor tags? You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822486/263773). Here's a modified answer to return the length of some html code.

```
function plainTextLength(html) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("div");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    var txt = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
    return txt.length;
}
```

This also works for your example above.

Comment: I am going to try this out.  Thanks Jeff

Answer (score 0):

If the input should be a string:

```
function getLength (string) {
     return string.match(/<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/)[1].length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactely sure what you need, but this function returns 11 for your example text:

```
function count(textareaInput) {  
  var count = 0;  
  $(textareaInput).filter('a').each(function() { 
    count += $(this).text().length;
  });
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    $('#count').text( this.value.replace(/<\/?a\s*[^>]*>/g, '').length );
});
```

[See working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/snwdm/4/).

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = document.getElementById('link');
var b = a.outerHTML.length - a.innerHTML.length;
```

I didn't test it, but it might work.